# Set the number of inverted commas automatically based on document language

Tags: punctuation, languages, babel

For some languages, `babel` would automatically interpret the inverted commas and convert it to the proper form of the selected language. For example, with Hungarian, when one begins a quotation and writes ``` `` ```, babel would automatically convert it to `,,` (which is the proper opening of a quotation in Hungarian). However, when I set the language option to British, babel won't do the same kind of conversion (AFAIK British typesetting uses single inverted commas for quotations, so I would expect `babel` to convert automatically the ``` `` ``` to `` ` `` when starting a quotation). Is there a reason why this automatic conversion doesn't work? Or is there a package option that would enable this conversion?

Comment: [csquotes](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) may come close to what you want, by giving you commands that are, amongst other things, language-sensitive, but I don't think they'll trigger on the customary double-backtick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that `babel` pulls off this 'trick' in Hungarian is by making `` ` `` an 'active' character, which converts the input into the appropriate macro. In principal one could do this in UK English, but it's not quite as clear-cut (the use of single *versus* double quote marks is a common but not universal difference between US and UK typography). Moreover, a more robust and clearer approach is offered by `csquotes`, which avoids the use of active characters (which can be tricky to handle correctly) and makes the fact that a quote is exactly that much clearer

```
\enquote{text} % Language-sensitive appearance
```